# How to change values from one column to another in a dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1- This is my Dataframe

```
Date        Open        Buy_Entry   Sell_Entry
2015-08-31  49.419998   np.nan      np.nan
2015-09-01  48.110001   np.nan      np.nan
2015-09-02  48.660000   np.nan      np.nan
2015-09-03  49.840000   np.nan      np.nan
2015-09-04  48.810001   np.nan      np.nan
... ... ... ...
2020-09-14  17.940001   np.nan      np.nan
2020-09-15  17.200001   Buy Entry   np.nan
2020-09-16  16.100000   Buy Entry   np.nan
2020-09-17  15.800000   np.nan      np.nan
2020-09-18  15.960000   np.nan      np.nan
1273 rows × 3 columns
```

2- Now, I need to convert into something like this:

```
Date        Open        Buy_Entry   Sell_Entry
2015-08-31  49.419998   np.nan      np.nan
2015-09-01  48.110001   np.nan      np.nan
2015-09-02  48.660000   np.nan      np.nan
2015-09-03  49.840000   np.nan      np.nan
2015-09-04  48.810001   np.nan      np.nan
... ... ... ...
2020-09-14  17.940001   np.nan      np.nan
2020-09-15  17.200001   17.200001   np.nan
2020-09-16  16.100000   16.100000   np.nan
2020-09-17  15.800000   np.nan      np.nan
2020-09-18  15.960000   np.nan      np.nan
1273 rows × 3 columns
```

I have no problem to replace the np.nan values to 0, but those "Buy Entry" are neccesary to be replaced
with the "Open" value in that exactly point (index)

Anny suggestion ?

I appreciate your help guys. regards!

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `df.loc` and series string search:

```
df["Buy_Entry"] = df.loc[df["Buy_Entry"].str.contains("Buy Entry"),"Open"]
```

Or

```
df.loc[~df["Buy_Entry"].isna(), "Buy_Entry"] = df["Open"]
```

Comment: Nope ! I did not work, I don´t know why, any other suggestion ?

Comment: What error are you getting? And the final output will reflect in df.

Comment: When I run the code, the column with "Buy_Entry" label gets the whole "Open" column data, I mean, I only need to change those values with "Buy Entry", but instead of that is changing all of the values from "Buy_Entry" column

Comment: @Fernando_G use the first one according to your need. It will work. change the value in ```.str.contains``` with the one you want.